# Create Reusable Functions with Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have a function that returns other functions like so:

```
export const makeAudienceDb = () => {
  async function insert({ ...params }: AudienceAttributes) {
    const audience = await AudienceModel.create({ ...params })
    const audienceToJson = audience.toJSON()
    return audienceToJson
  }

  async function findById({ id }: { id: number }) {
    const user = await AudienceModel.findByPk(id)
    return user?.toJSON()
  }

  async function remove({ id }: { id: number }) {
    return AudienceModel.destroy({ where: { id } })
  }

  async function update({
    id,
    ...changes
  }: { id: number } & AudienceAttributes) {
    const updated = await AudienceModel.update(
      { ...changes },
      { where: { id } }
    )
    return updated
  }

  return Object.freeze({
    insert,
    findById,
    remove,
    update,
  })
}
```

I have other models, e.g `UserModel`, `PostModel` which have the same database operations as `makeAudienceDb`. e.g

```
export const makeUsersDb = ({ hashPassword, createToken }: DBDeps) => {
  async function insert({ ...params }: User) {
    if (params.password) {
      params.password = await hashPassword(params.password)
    }
    const newUser = await UserModel.create({ ...params })
    const returnedUser = newUser.toJSON()

    const { id } = newUser
    const { name, username, email, password } = returnedUser as User
    const payload = {
      id,
      email,
    }
    const token = createToken(payload)
    const user = { id, name, username, password, email }
    return { user, token }
  }

  async function findById({ id }: { id: number }) {
    const user = await UserModel.findByPk(id)
    return user?.toJSON()
  }

  async function findByEmail({ email }: { email: string }) {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ where: { email } })
    return user?.toJSON()
  }

  async function remove({ id }: { id: number }) {
    return UserModel.destroy({ where: { id } })
  }

  async function update({ id, ...changes }: { id: number } & User) {
    const updated = await UserModel.update({ ...changes }, { where: { id } })
    return updated
  }

  return Object.freeze({
    insert,
    findByEmail,
    findById,
    remove,
    update,
  })
}
```

This leads to code duplication across various levels. I want to know how to create one major function that I can reuse for other database operations. So instead of me having `makeAudienceDb`, `makeUsersDb`, I could just have one major function e.g `majorDatabaseOps` where `makeAudienceDb` and `makeUsersDb` could just inherit from. I know this is possible with ES6 Classes and `Interfaces` but I was just wondering how I could implement the same in a functional way. Any contribution is welcome. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are trying to do is bind shortcuts to particular sequelize methods.  The shared functionality can be implemented using typescript generics.  Overriding specific behaviors, like hashing a password for a `User` makes this a bit more complex.

My first instinct is to use a class-based approach. But you can do it with functions by copying all of the methods from the base and then overriding or adding specific ones, along these lines:

```
const userDb = Object.freeze({
  ...makeDb(UserModel), 
  findByEmail: async ({email}: {email: string}) => {
  }
})
```

We want to create a function that takes the model as an argument.  It will use typescript generics to describe the types associated with that model.  The generics will be inferred from the `model` variable when calling the function.

A sequelize `Model` has two generic values: `TModelAttributes` and `TCreationAttributes` which is optional and defaults to `TModelAttributes`.  We also want to require that all of our model attributes must include `{id: number}`.

You could potentially add additional typings to get better support for `toJSON`.  The sequelize package just declares the return type from `Model.toJSON` as `object` which is vague and unhelpful.

Our general function looks like this:

```
import {Model, ModelCtor} from "sequelize";

export const makeDb = <TModelAttributes extends {id: number} = any, TCreationAttributes extends {} = TModelAttributes>(
    model: ModelCtor<Model<TModelAttributes, TCreationAttributes>>
  ) => {
  async function insert({ ...params }: TCreationAttributes) {
    const created = await model.create({ ...params });
    return created.toJSON();
  }

  async function findById({ id }: { id: number }) {
    const found = await model.findByPk(id)
    return found?.toJSON()
  }

  async function remove({ id }: { id: number }) {
    return model.destroy({ where: { id } })
  }

  async function update({ ...changes }: { id: number } & Partial<TModelAttributes>) {
    const { id } = changes; // I get a TS error when destructuring this in the args
    const updated = await model.update(
      { ...changes },
      { where: { id } }
    );
    return updated;
  }

  return Object.freeze({
    insert,
    findById,
    remove,
    update,
  });
}
```

For audience, you would simply call:

```
const audienceDb = makeDb(AudienceModel);
```

Or you could define it as a function if you wanted to:

```
const makeAudienceDb = () => makeDb(AudienceModel);
```

For the users database, we need to override `insert`, add `findByEmail`, and take additional arguments `hashPassword` and `createToken`.

This is not elegant, but it should work. I don't love that your return type for user `insert` is incompatible with the `insert` returned value from the general `makeDb`.

```
export const makeUsersDb = ({ hashPassword, createToken }: DBDeps) => {

  // declaring this up top so that you could call methods on it in your overrides
  const db = makeDb(UserModel);

  async function insert({ ...params }: User) {
    if (params.password) {
      params.password = await hashPassword(params.password)
    }
    const newUser = await UserModel.create({ ...params })
    const returnedUser = newUser.toJSON()

    const { id } = newUser
    const { name, username, email, password } = returnedUser as User
    const payload = {
      id,
      email,
    }
    const token = createToken(payload)
    const user = { id, name, username, password, email }
    return { user, token }
  }

  async function findByEmail({ email }: { email: string }) {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ where: { email } })
    return user?.toJSON()
  }

  return Object.freeze({
    ...db,
    insert,
    findByEmail
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the common functions outside of the `majorDatabaseOps` function? Will let you reuse them in different places.

```js
//defined outside for reusability
function findById(model, id) {
  return model.findByPk(id)
}

const majorDatabaseOps = model => {
  
  function removeById(model, id) {
    return model.remove(id);
  }

  return Object.freeze({
    removeById: id => removeById(model, id),
    findById: id => findById(model, id),
  })
}

//mocking models for demonstration
const UserModel = {
  modelName: "UserModel",
  findByPk: function(id) {
    return console.log(id + " was found in " + this.modelName)
  },
  remove: function(id) {
    return console.log(id + " was removed from " + this.modelName)
  }
}

const PostModel = {
  modelName: "PostModel",
  findByPk: function(id) {
    return console.log(id + " was found in " + this.modelName)
  },
  remove: function(id) {
    return console.log(id + " was removed from " + this.modelName)
  }
}


const userDbOps = majorDatabaseOps(UserModel);
userDbOps.findById(1);
userDbOps.removeById(1);

const postDbOps = majorDatabaseOps(PostModel);
postDbOps.findById(2);
postDbOps.removeById(2);
```